# How to modify AnsiStrPos function to return integer offset? (Delphi 7)

Tags: string, delphi, pointers

I am using Delphi 7 and I want function similar to ansipos, but it should use input offset argument and return integer offset. I have found code similar to this here https://github.com/Fr0sT-Brutal/Delphi_MiniRTL/blob/master/SysUtils.pas and I want to modify the output to be integer offset. How can I get the integer offset from PChar?

```
function AnsiStrPos(Str, SubStr: PChar): PChar;
var
  L1, L2: Cardinal;
  ByteType : TMbcsByteType;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Str = nil) or (Str^ = #0) or (SubStr = nil) or (SubStr^ = #0) then Exit;
  L1 := StrLen(Str);
  L2 := StrLen(SubStr);
  Result := StrPos(Str, SubStr);
  while (Result <> nil) and ((L1 - Cardinal(Result - Str)) >= L2) do
  begin
    ByteType := StrByteType(Str, Integer(Result-Str));
    if (ByteType <> mbTrailByte) and
      (AnsiCompareStr(Result, SubStr) = 0) then Exit;
    if (ByteType = mbLeadByte) then Inc(Result);
    Inc(Result);
    Result := StrPos(Result, SubStr);
  end;
  Result := nil;
end;
```

For example str := "sub_string"; From "sub_string" I want find "string", start to search from position 4 and the result should be 0.

Comment: Specific reason you want to use PChars, and not normal strings? Have you met `PosEx`?

Comment: I did not know about this function in StrUtils. Thanx for that point.

Comment: `PosEx()` is declared and defined in the file you linked to - it was already there in front of you.

Comment: PosEx will use the absolute offset, but you can easily wrap it in a function that does something like `Result := PosEx(SubStr, YourString, Offset) - Offset;`. The result will be `< 0` if the string is not found (provided you specify a valid offset that is >= 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
function AnsiStrOffset(AStr, ASubStr: PChar; const AStartPos: Cardinal = 0): Integer;
var
  VPos: PChar;
begin
  Result := -1; // not found
  if StrLen(AStr) <= AStartPos then begin
    Exit;
  end;
  Inc(AStr, AStartPos);
  VPos := AnsiStrPos(AStr, ASubStr);
  if VPos <> nil then begin
    Result := Int64(VPos) - Int64(AStr);
    // add AStartPos to Result if you need offset from the string beginning
  end;
end;
```

usage:

```
var
  VOffs: Integer;
  VStr, VSubStr: string;
begin
  VStr := 'sub_string';
  VSubStr := 'string';

  VOffs := AnsiStrOffset(PChar(VStr), PChar(VSubStr), 4);

  WriteLn(VOffs); // prints 0
end;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the solution. This saves me a lot of problems which I had with ansipos() and DIRegex.match() functions last week.

Comment: @user why not debug it yourself?

Comment: Why even using `PChar` at all when all input stems from `String` anyway?

Comment: If you know it how to do it better, you can write one. I am not skilled with this stuff, I just looked on internet to find some function which would better fit my needs than ansipos or regex match.

Comment: The usage of this function is conditioned by the length of the input strings, which must be longer than 1 char, or I need to add \0 to the end of the string.. Like PChar('$'+chr(0))

Comment: @user1141649 all the more reason to change the function to take `String` input instead of `PChar` input

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: GolezTrol above told me to use PosEx in StrUtils; I did know know about this function (and nobody told me that it even exists when I asked programmers before).